# Android AlarmManager disabled after phone reboot

Tags: android, android-alarms

Sorry to repost the same question but I read every post on that question and did exactly what they said, but i can't get it work. So please read my code and tell what i did wrong below:

**Schedule the alarm : **

```
  public void progr(View v){

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    //calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12); // For 1 PM or 2 PM
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 36);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 1);
    Long time = calendar.getTimeInMillis();//new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis()+10*1000;


    Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(this, AlarmReciever.class);

    // create the object
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    //set the alarm for particular time
    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, 5000, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
    Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Scheduled for Tommrrow", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, DeviceBootReceiver.class);
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

}
```

**Alarmreceiver extends Broadcast :**

```
public class AlarmReciever extends BroadcastReceiver
{
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{

     {

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(Main.context)
                    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(Main.context.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("Zall - Notification")
                    .setContentText("Veuillez cliquer pour epargner votre crédit.");

    Intent intentnot = new Intent(Main.context, Main.class);
    intentnot.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(Main.context, 0, intentnot, 0);

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) Main.context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    int mId = 1234567890;

    Notification mNotification = mBuilder.build();
    mNotification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    mNotification.contentIntent = pendingIntent;
    mNotification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
    mNotificationManager.notify(mId, mNotification);
    }
}

}
```

**DeviceBootReceiver to reschedule the alarm after device boot**

```
public class DeviceBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();;

        //calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12); // For 1 PM or 2 PM
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 27);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 1);
        Long time = calendar.getTimeInMillis();//new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis()+10*1000;

        // create an Intent and set the class which will execute when Alarm triggers, here we have
        // given AlarmReciever in the Intent, the onRecieve() method of this class will execute when
        // alarm triggers and
        //we will write the code to send SMS inside onRecieve() method pf Alarmreciever class
        Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(Main.context, AlarmReciever.class);

        // create the object
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) Main.context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        //set the alarm for particular time
        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,time,AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Main.context, 1, intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
        Toast.makeText(Main.context, "Alarm Scheduled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

}

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.exercicesextrasapks.onezero.intussd" >



<uses-permission android:name="android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Main"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>



    <receiver  android:name=".AlarmReciever">

    </receiver>
    <receiver android:enabled="false" android:name=".DeviceBootReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>


</application>
```

Comment: "i can't get it work" -- please explain what you mean by this. Please also use tools like **`adb shell dumpsys alarm`** to see what alarms you have scheduled.

Comment: (sorry for bad english)
Setting alarm to ring works perfectly, i'm just trying to make it work even when the device reboots

Comment: Is your `DeviceBootReceiver` is being called on `BOOT_COMPLETED`?? 

As @CommonsWare said in your   
`command promt`.Type this  ,  `adb shell dumpsys alarm > alarmLog.txt`. This will generate a text file in the current path. search for you package name in that file and see your current active alarms

Comment: Sorry, I'm testiong on real device and i do not if i have to dowbload a command prompt or not

Comment: I've download Terminal emulator and i get "can't create alarmLog.txt Read-only file system"

Answer (score 0):

Your receiver for .DeviceBootReceiver should look like this

```
<receiver android:name=".DeviceBootReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver> code here
```

You need to allow your receiver to receive messages from things outside your application.  [Read this for more information](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html).

Comment: The only other thing I see is that you might want to change your flag in your Boot Receiver from `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`  to `PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT`.  When you reboot your device any Pending intents are lost.  So, at that point you have nothing to update.

Comment: Why aren't you setting the Date Portion of your calendar.  The second parameter of  void setInexactRepeating is the "time in milliseconds that the alarm should first go off" [Source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setInexactRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29).  If you run your code after 12:27pm local time then you're setting the first time that your alarm should go off in the past.

Comment: Still not working....even after replace the flag and add:   calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);